# How do I write a mathematical equation for ARIMA (0,2,1) x (0,0,1) period 12

Tags: time-series, arima

I would appreciate if someone could help me write the mathematical equation for the seasonal ARIMA (0,2,1) x (0,0,1) period 12. I'm a little confused with how to go about this. I would prefer an equation involving $Y_{t}$ , $e_{t}$, $\theta$ and $\Theta$.

I really don't want an equation involving the backshift operator.

Comment: See http://otexts.com/fpp/8/9/

Comment: @RobHyndman: just wanted to thank you again. The material was really helpful.

Comment: This is okay but how do you know that the period is 12 months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $SARIMA(0,2,1)\times(0,0,1)_{12}$ we have $\phi_0(B)(1-B)^2\Phi_0(B^{12})(1-B^{12})^0 Y_t = \theta_1(B)\Theta_1(B^{12})e_t$, where

$\phi_0(B)=\Phi_0(B^{12})=1$

and

$\theta_1(B)= 1+\theta_1B$,

$\Theta_1(B^{12})=1+\Theta_1B^{12}$.

And the result is

$Y_t-2Y_{t-1}+Y_{t-2}=e_t+\Theta_1e_{t-12}+\theta_1e_{t-1}+\theta_1\Theta_1e_{t-13}$

Comment: Often the parameterization involves terms of the form $(1-\theta_1B)$ and $(1-\Theta_1B^{12})$. If you are using a computer package, check which parameterization is implemented.

Comment: @Alpha: Yeah. thanks again. I have accepted it. But i was wondering if you could check the second term after the equal sign again. Should the e_{t-1} have a parameter of "theta" while the e_{t-12} have a parameter "Theta"?

Comment: @b2amen Yes, you are right. I am sorry for my mistake, I edited the answer.

Comment: Sorry to pick up on an old thread, but I have a concern with your polynomial developments of the two theta's, as I learned that the MA operator (here both theta and Theta) were represented as polynomials with a **minus sign**, therefore I would have written θ1(B)=1 - θ1B, Θ1(B12)=1 - Θ1B12, which changes the sign in the final answer too
Yt−2Yt−1+Yt−2=et - Θ1et−12 - θ1et−1 + θ1Θ1et−13...?