# Time series difference operator

Tags: time-series, self-study, differences

I have a question regarding the difference operator of SARIMA models. I am attempting to write out $SARIMA(2,1,2)(2,1,1)_{24}$. This seasonal ARIMA model has therefore 2 difference operators.

I have tried to follow various different posts on here ... especially this one:

[How To Write Seasonal ARIMA model mathematically](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82197/how-to-write-seasonal-arima-model-mathematically)

However, I am in doubt whether this is actually done correctly. Currently I have the following:

$\nabla^1_{24}\nabla^1X_t$ = $\nabla^1_{24}(X_t-X_{t-1})$ = $X_t-X_{t-1}-X_{t-24}$

Perhaps there is an equation which explains it in more detail (step-wise)?

Thank you in advance.