# How to interpret output from forecast package

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

The `forecast` package has the function `auto.arima` and `forecast` to model time-series. Understanding the output is proving difficult for me. Particularly, the model selection nomenclature.

[image]

What does `ARIMA(2,0,2)(1,0,0)[12] with zero mean` stand for?

Let's be clear, I understand the `ARIMA(p,d,q)` format. `p` is the autoregressive component, `d` is the degree of difference, i.e. integration component, and `q` stands for the moving-average component. So I understand the basics of what makes up an autoregressive integrated moving-average model.

I am asking specifically about the use of two arima models side by side, `[12]`, and `with zero mean`. Did `auto.arima` have a tie with the best models and used both? First a lag of 2 then a lag of one? Then use 12 as the season frequency for annual seasonality and change a regular mean to zero?

Reproducible example:

```
ts.count <- structure(c(899, 567, 590, 162, -68, -142, -34, -6, 41, 56, 38, 
34, 168, 405, 425, 385, 304, 694, 531, 766, 792, 585, 236, 648, 
813, 990, 776, 947, 599, 651, 1317, 1066, 1212, 1232, 621, 1945, 
2676, 3102, 2798, 2388, 1833, 1533, 2749, 1428, 2272, 2390, 1126, 
2634, 3553, 4182, 4553, 4419, 3686, 3380, 3862, 4288, 4850, 4228, 
2696, 5109, 8571, 9039, 7997, 6537, 5519, 4722, 5374, 5841, 7290, 
5419, 835, 4606, 10823, 15203, 15018, 14147, 13593, 15166, 12813, 
16114, 14261, 9933, 7218, 10873, 18894, 30201, 27298, 22505, 
13526, 16945, 13409, 27298, 27313, 31355, 29437, 41552), .Tsp = c(2008.08333333333, 
2016, 12), class = "ts")

plot(forecast(auto.arima(ts.count)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does `ARIMA(2,0,2)(1,0,0)[12] with zero mean` stand for?

You got a seasonal ARIMA (i.e. SARIMA) model with regular orders $(p,d,q)=(2,0,2)$, seasonal orders $(P,D,Q)=(1,0,0)$ and seasonal period 12 (e.g. monthly data). There is no intercept in the model (the intercept was set to zero).

> I am asking specifically about the use of two arima models side by side, `[12]`, and `with zero mean`. Did `auto.arima` have a tie with the best models and used both? First a lag of 2 then a lag of one? Then use 12 as the season frequency for annual seasonality and change a regular mean to zero?

- You got one model, namely, `ARIMA(2,0,2)(1,0,0)[12] with zero mean` -- not two models side by side.
- `with zero mean` just means there is no intercept in the model and the unconditional mean of the series is modelled to be zero.
- `[12]` is just the seasonal frequency.

See Hyndman & Athanasopoulos "Forecasting: Principles and Practice" section 8.9 ["Seasonal ARIMA models"](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/9). See also [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61510/how-do-i-write-a-mathematical-equation-for-arima-0-2-1-x-0-0-1-period-12?rq=1) and [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69407/how-do-i-write-a-mathematical-equation-for-arima-2-1-0-x-0-2-2-period-12?rq=1) for mathematical representation of particular seasonal ARIMA models.

Comment: You are very welcome!