# What is the equation for ARIMA (1,0,1)?

Tags: arima

I know in terms of $y$, the general forecasting equation is:
$$
\hat{y}_t = \mu + \varphi_1 y_{t-1} + \dots + \varphi_p y_{t-p} - \theta_1e_{t-1} - \dots - \theta_qe_{t-q}.
$$
I also know that ARIMA(1,0,0) = first-order autoregressive model: 
$$
\hat{y}_t = \mu + \varphi_1y_{t-1}.
$$

Can someone tell me how I can write the equation for an ARIMA (1, 0, 1)?

Comment: See [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69407/how-do-i-write-a-mathematical-equation-for-arima-2-1-0-x-0-2-2-period-12) and [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61510/how-do-i-write-a-mathematical-equation-for-arima-0-2-1-x-0-0-1-period-12?rq=1) which are possibly duplicates. See also the related questions to the above ones in the right panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by the general forecasting equation and I am not sure I understand your notation.  Are you staying in the ARIMA realm?

The AR(1) model ARIMA(1,0,0) has the form: $Y_t = r Y_{t-1} + e_t$   where $r$ is the autoregressive parameter and $e_t$ is the pure error term at time $t$.

For ARIMA(1,0,1) it is simply $Y_t = r Y_{t-1} + e_t + a e_{t-1}$ where $a$ is the moving average parameter.