# How to write a seasonal SRIMA model (0,1,1)*(1,1,1) [12] mathematically?

Tags: time-series, arma

I find SRIMA model (0,1,1)*(1,1,1)[12] to fit my time series model but i don't know how to write the model with mathematical way. I need help.

Comment: You can also try reading [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/69407/), & [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/61510/).

Comment: I think you will find the information you need in the linked thread. Please 
read it. If it isn't what you want / you still have a question afterwards, 
come back here & edit your question to state what you learned & what you still 
need to know. Then we can provide the information you need without just 
duplicating material elsewhere that already didn't help you.